# How to delete a config file content with ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build-tools

I want to delete a file content with ant, because it is a config file and I want it to be empty in the jar file.

```
<replaceregexp file="src/config.properties" match="*" replace=""/>

Error:
Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*
^
```

Comment: Does `<replaceregexp file="src/config.properties" match="[\s\S]*" replace=""/>` work?

Comment: @howlger Thanks. it works. but is this way the config file becomes empty. Is there any way to export a jar file with empty config file but the config file in the project not change?